Imageviewbutton not showing Image
I have two buttons one provides search functionality and the other one shows a print button. The search button is showing perfectly but the Imageviewbutton is not showing an image just a small dot is display
here is my code what exactly I am making a mistake
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
     <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_filter"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Filter"
        android:visible="false"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_tune_black_24dp" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="0"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
   <item
        android:id="@+id/action_print"
        android:icon="@drawable/print"
        android:title="Print"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:visible="true"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
 </menu>

